# Error 'free(): double free detected in tcache 2'

Tags: c

I'm getting the error stated in the title trying to close a file.
Here is the snippet (headers are included in case there are incompatibilities I'm not aware of)

```
/***  HEADER FILES TO INCLUDE          ***/

/* Standard Header Files*/
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>  // usleep()

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include "SocketsConWin.c"
#define stat _stat
#else
#include "SocketsCon.c"
#endif

/***  DEFINES                          ***/
/* Maximum length for error messages*/
#define ERR_MSG_LEN 250 
/* Base directory for output files*/
#define BASE_OUT "output_files/"
/* Base directory for input files*/
#define BASE_IN "input_files/"
```

Actual code:

```
//rest of the code
FILE *json_file = NULL;
json_file = fopen(json_filename, "rb+");
if (json_file != NULL) {  // the json file for the event exists
    if (read_file(json_file, &json_string)) {
        *error_msg = malloc(ERR_MSG_LEN);
        snprintf(*error_msg, ERR_MSG_LEN, "Error reading the json file\n");
        free(json_string);
        fclose(json_file);
        return;
    }
    json_event = cJSON_Parse(json_string);
    free(json_string);
    fclose(json_file);
} else {  // the file does not exist
    char base_name[] = "base_event.json";
    len = strlen(BASE_IN) + strlen(base_name) + 1;
    char *base_file_name = malloc(len);
    snprintf(base_file_name, len, "%s%s", BASE_IN, base_name);
    FILE *json_file = fopen(base_file_name, "rb+");
    
    if (json_file == NULL) {
        *error_msg = malloc(ERR_MSG_LEN);
        snprintf(*error_msg, ERR_MSG_LEN, "Error reading the json base file\n");
        fclose(json_file);
        free(base_file_name);
        return;
    }
    if (read_file(json_file, &json_string)) {
        fclose(json_file);
        *error_msg = malloc(ERR_MSG_LEN);
        snprintf(*error_msg, ERR_MSG_LEN, "Error reading the json base file\n");
        if (json_string != NULL)
            free(json_string);
        return;
    }
    fclose(json_file);
    free(base_file_name);        

    json_event = cJSON_Parse(json_string);

    free(json_string);
    //rest of the code
   }
```

Using debugger to inspect the program behaviour isn't very useful as the file pointer is initialized and working before calling *fclose* function, so I'm quite perplexed

Comment: You have `json_file = fopen(...);` once at the start of your function and later on in the `else` block, but you never close the first file.

Comment: Check why the first fopen call fails; check `errno`. It is likely some allocation happens in the first fopen call, even though it ends up failing. Hence in this case, you may indeed have to call fclose for the first fopen.

Comment: Are you sure what you pass to `fclose` is valid? Closing the same file twice, or passing NULL to `fclose`, are both undefined behavior.

Comment: @Joel I tried, but since the file is not there (json_file is NULL if fopen fails) i got a segmantation fault if I close it.

Comment: Does `//error handling` contain a `free()` call but not a `return`, per chance?

Comment: @Lundin nope, the error handling prints a log message, closes `json_file`, frees `base_file_name` and returns, but it's not triggered, since the base_file exists

Comment: I think we need to see the `//do stuff` part then. From what you have posted so far and your comments it seems there is nothing wrong and especially nothing that can lead to "still working right before the fclose but the fclose segfaults".

Comment: I just edited the answer, now it shows the complete if-else

Comment: but you are calling `fclose(NULL)` in your `if` branch, aren't you? Regardless of whether it would fix your original issue, you should fix the code to not call `fclose` on `NULL`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou in the first `if` the `json_file` is NOT null, so I can safely close it, in the `else` branch i open (correctly) another file but I'm unable to close it

Comment: I mean the if inside your else branch. `if(json_file==NULL){...fclose(json_file);...}`

Comment: @WeijunZhou you're right, this is a potential problem, I'm fixing it, but as for the question I'm not triggering that `if` condition (since the base json file exists), so there is neither `fclose(NULL)` nor a double `fclose` invocation

Answer (score 1):

You've made a bit of a mess of the resource allocation/clean-up as well as code repetition. In this case I think the easiest way to recover the program is to use the old-school "on error goto" trick, centralizing all clean-up at the bottom of the function.

Other things of note:

- Calling free() with a null pointer parameter is well-defined.
- Always check the result of malloc().
- Assuming `error` is a `char**`, there's no obvious need for dynamic allocation. Just let it point at a string literal instead.

The first step towards cleaning up the program might look like this:

```c
    char *json_string = NULL;
    char *base_file_name = NULL;
    FILE *json_file = NULL;

    json_file = fopen(json_filename, "rb+");
    if(json_file == NULL) {
        // the file does not exist
        const char base_name[] = "base_event.json";
        len = strlen(BASE_IN) + strlen(base_name) + 1;

        base_file_name = malloc(len);
        if(base_file_name == NULL) {
            *error_msg = "Error - out of heap memory"
            goto cleanup;
        }

        snprintf(base_file_name, len, "%s%s", BASE_IN, base_name);
        json_file = fopen(base_file_name, "rb+");
        if (json_file == NULL) {
            *error_msg = "Error reading the json file\n";
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }

    if (read_file(json_file, &json_string)) {
        *error_msg = "Error reading the json file\n";
        goto cleanup;
    }

    json_event = cJSON_Parse(json_string);

    // rest of code

cleanup:
    if(json_file)
        fclose(json_file);
    free(base_file_name);
    free(json_string);
} // end of function
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to implement it in my function, as you can see [here](https://pastebin.com/hH0ACiZt) . Unfortunately it still triggers the same error in the marked location. Maybe an explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish here is necessary. This function writes some data into a json file called `json_filename`. If the file does not exist I need to write some standard data BEFORE the actual data, that's why I open `base_event.json`. I'm running out of ideas on out to accomplish this task